# Can't style my checkbox as `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` or `right: 0`

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I can't style my checkbox as `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` or `right: 0`.

I want to put the checkbox top and right but there is weird padding on the photo. I tried many different styles but none of them works. :(

[image]

This is FlatList's renderItem()

```
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
       style={{flex:1}}
      onPress={() => this._handleImagePress(item.id, item.outfit_img)}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Image
          key={item.id}
          source={{uri: item.outfit_img}}
          style={styles.rowImage}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
        <CheckBox checked={isSelected} style={{marginLeft:2, marginTop:2, position:'absolute', alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}/>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Here is FlatList function

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.outfits}
          extraData={this.state.selectedStyles}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          numColumns={3}
          renderHeader={this._renderHeader}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

**UPDATE FIX** I guess Native-Base Checkbox is terrible on styling. This is working version. Any optimization? or better option?

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
       style={{flex:1}}
      onPress={() => this._handleImagePress(item.id, item.outfit_img)}>
      <View style={styles.rowImage}>
        <Image
          key={item.id}
          source={{uri: item.outfit_img}}
          style={styles.rowImage}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
        <View style={{height:32, width:32, position:'absolute', top:0, right:0, marginTop:4, paddingRight:12}}>
          <CheckBox checked={isSelected} color="#f64e59"/>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a snack here https://snack.expo.io/HJYNoAEAW , hopefully you are expecting this behaviour.

Comment: The actual issue was native-base Checkbox.. I put 2 hours to figure this out :( so bad

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely positioned children of the flex container are not flex items anymore and therefore don't obey flex alignment properties (`align-*` and `justify-*`). They *do* obey offset keywords (`left`, `right`, etc.), but these offsets are calculated relatively to the closest *positioned* ancestor (or, if there is none, to the root element). Try adding `position:'relative'` to your `TouchableWithoutFeedback` element's `style` attribute to make it the nearest positioned ancestor of the checkbox, so it could be positioned relatively to it.

Comment: I left `position: 'absolute'` on checkbox and put `position: 'relative'` to `TouchableWithoutOpacity`. It still renders same thing. Am I doing wrong? I put my exact code to my question. - Question is edited

Comment: Didn't you also add `right:0` (instead of `alignSelf`) for the checkbox?

Comment: I tried many different approaches but the problem was native-base's checkbox. I just edited the question with working version if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` from the CheckBox instead add `justify-content: space-between` to the parent of the element.

Comment: I just tried your version but it renders another row for the checkbox. However what I'm trying to build is checkbox on the image.

Comment: Thanks for concrete answer though I appreciate it